# Ajax call working fine with Chrome but not with IE7

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7

First I want to say that this problem is only happening when using Internet Explorer 7, when I use Chrome everything works just fine.

So, the problem I have is the following, I got a really simple PHP file that has an input box for a document number, then it has a submit button, that is pretty much it,  the problem (I think) comes where I call a second PHP file using Ajax (this file is in charge of querying a MYSQL data base and returning a table and a graph with some data) but when I run IE7 I don't get anything after the **succes function:(response)** is called.

Here is the function where I call the second file:

```
function realizaProceso(valorDocumento){
    var parametros = {
            "valorDocumento" : valorDocumento
    };
    if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {

        } else {

        }

    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros + "&r=" + Math.random(),
            cache: false,
            url:   'proceso.php',
            type:  'post',
            dataType : 'text',
            beforeSend: function () {

                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {

                    $("#resultado").html(response);
            }
    });
```

}

As you can see I have already tried some of the things that were suggested on symilar threads on this website, such as using the **cache: false,** or adding some random generated data on each call.

Here is a [Link](http://pastebin.com/LPLR4NzU) to the full PHP file.

**<--UPDATE-->**

So after following some of the suggestions you guys gave me, I can finally call the other PHP file, now the problem is that even thought I can call it, for some reason IE7 is not parsing what the PHP script is returning, here is a [Link to the proceso.php file](http://pastebin.com/f4P5AXMR), thanks in advance!

Comment: I bet you use jQuery 2.0, don't you?

Comment: He is using jquery-1.8.3.js

Comment: I note that you're using `$.browser` to detect IE7. Please note that `$.browser` is deprecated (as far back as jQuery 1.3), so not recommended to use if you can avoid it. It's been removed entirely from more recent versions of jQuery (1.9 onward).

Comment: I can take out the if **if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7)** and it will keep working on Chrome but not on IE7

Answer (score 1):

There are already a few posts on Stack Overflow with multiple solutions related to javascript parsing, jQuery not fully supporting IE7 (however this could be version based), and html formatted in a way that IE7 doesn't approve of. You can find these answers here:

[jQuery AJAX problem in IE7 (possibly other versions as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318743/jquery-ajax-problem-in-ie7-possibly-other-versions-as-well)

[jQuery .ajax method in IE7 & IE6 not working but working fine in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320090/jquery-ajax-method-in-ie7-ie6-not-working-but-working-fine-in-firefox)

Comment: You do realize that these questions are 3 years old. I would think that these kind of bugs are more or less ironed out now.

Comment: Heh, nope, didn't notice that. However, i do know that IE7 is quite the beast to tame.